# How to select MySQL same table with multi values condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

Here is the the table `activities`

```
        id| uid | acid | type    |topic
        1 | 01  | 05   | followu |0
        2 | 01  | 06   | followu |0
        3 | 06  | 23   | asked   |5
        4 | 06  | 23   | answered|0
        5 | 05  | 96   | comments|0
        6 | 01  | 5    | ftopic  |0
        7 | 01  | 23   | fasked  |0
        8 | 01  | 58   | asked   |7
        9 | 37  | 58   | answered|0
```

Here is description ,

- followu= UserID(`uid`) 01 Stated following userid(`acid`)  05 -->[for id=1]
- asked= `UserID 06` asking (Post) something and the post id=23 --> [for
  id=3]
- answered= `User ID 06` answered(Post) something for `acid=34` which is mainly id of asked 34 (which is shown id=3) -->[for id=4]
- comments= User ID 05 comments(Post) something and the post id=06 --> [for id=5]
- fasked= `UserID 01` Stated following a asked post [asked type] and the askedid(`acid`) =23 (The `askedid (acid)` is in id=3)--> [for id=7]

Mention:

1. So We can see that `Userid[01]` is following `Userid` 05,06
2. and also we can see some activities from `userid` 05,06
3. Here also we can see `Userid[01]` is following a `askedid=58` in `id=7` and ind `id=9`
   a another `userid 37` answered the question.

Summary:

So i wanted to make a feed list with php for userid01 whom he is following by type
followu fasked ftopic

I can get every activates from  followu userid(acid) Which is related in uid=userid(acid) but as we see the `userid(uid) 37` in `id=9` answered a Post Where acid=58 and that is related to `id=8` askedid(`acid`)=58 . So Userid(uid) will also get this `id=9` feed . as usual userid [01] following topic [type=ftopic] Where `topicid[acid=5]` So any `asked` type row will match the `acid` which is equal to `topicid[acid=5]` and these row also have to in feed list

So i tried,

```
$query = "select * from `activitis` where (`type`='fasked' OR `type`='fuser' OR `type`='ftopic') and `uid`='01'");
;
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  

////// Here we can get the following `userid` `topicid` and `askedid` Now we can select  `activities`table  like, for  `userid` selecting `uid` AND for `topicid` and `askedid` selecting `acid` 

///// But i also wanted the activites of my following userid askedid and topicid related But if I loop again in this Loop i have to loop for separated type `fasked` `fuser` and `ftopic` But i want result like `order by` `id` and mixed type feed. Just like facebook newsfeed its showing mixed type of feed.

}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand your question after reading it a few times. Could you please clarify? I also noticed this in your where clause: `uid`='01'
Is uid a character data type, or a number type?

Comment: I am sorry i didn't notice that actually uid a character data type character Or number type isn't really facts .
Too short Question :
You can see a table activities : Now make a feed list with php [i.e like facebook newsfeed]

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but unfortunately I still don't really understand your question :( Perhaps someone besides me will end up here and be able to answer for you

Comment: Yeah Thanks.. If i would describe like that "I have a site where people is following each other and following many topics Asking Questions Under Topics. And People are replying The Question,following the Question, Favorite the Question And Many of them making comments likes and voting the Answers" But Everything is saving in one table called activates . Now how can i separate Feeds for users depends on which users,topics,question are they following .....
That would be much clear but rapidly i would get downvote and On Hold . Someone Will Say Please read our terms "Did you tried it? LOL

Comment: So...you're re-making stack overflow? :/

Comment: nope something social like Blurit. I got challeged to make site like Blurit in 20 days alone with bootstrap,font-awesome,Jquary,summernote and Only PHP [without framework]
 
http://nekabbarermohaproyan.com/demo/